# How to change the color of the Youtube Like button using CSS

Tags: html, css, youtube

I have read the information in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69054554/how-to-change-the-color-of-the-youtube-like-button) but it seems to be outdated because it doesn't work for me!

I am using the Arc browser and a new feature called Boost whereby one can customize the looks of a web page using custom CSS rules.

Thus far, my custom CSS rules are as follows:

```css
.iron-selected {
  background-color: antiquewhite !important;
}

.iron-selected > #text {
  color: #000 !important;
}

.style-scope, .yt-spec-button-shape-next--mono.yt-spec-button-shape-next--tonal {
  color: #898989 !important;
}

ytd-app, .ytd-app, div#background, div#chips-wrapper {
  background-color: #0f0f0f !important;
}

.ytd-channel-name {
  color: #444 !important;
}
```

The 3rd CSS rule correctly changes the color of the thumbs down (dislike) button to a light gray, but the thumbs up (like) button remains black, as can be seen in the screenshot below:

[image: YouTube buttons below the video player]

I explored the HTML code below, but I don't understand where the like button gets its black color from or how to change it: (I've tried setting the color of various selectors but to no avail!)

[image: HTML code for the like button]

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

```css
#segmented-like-button
    > ytd-toggle-button-renderer
    > yt-button-shape
    > button
    > div.yt-spec-button-shape-next__icon
    > yt-icon
    > yt-animated-icon
    > ytd-lottie-player
    > lottie-component
    > svg
    > g
    > g:nth-child(2)
    > g:nth-child(4)
    > path,
#segmented-like-button
    > ytd-toggle-button-renderer
    > yt-button-shape
    > button
    > div.yt-spec-button-shape-next__icon
    > yt-icon
    > yt-animated-icon
    > ytd-lottie-player
    > lottie-component
    > svg
    > g
    > g:nth-child(2)
    > g:nth-child(2)
    > path {
    stroke: #898989 !important; /* Set the desired color */
}
```

Comment: Hi InSync, nicely formatted! Neat and clear! Thank you! I wonder how you did that.